# Using Instance or Static Method for reusable method

Tags: c#, performance

I have made a lot of forms for my desktop application, some forms were using the same method which I have to copy and paste the code (not OOP).

Let's say I have a method called `FirstDayOfWeek()` and this method is needed in 5 forms, that means I need to copy and paste the code 4 times to the other forms.

What I want to ask is:

1. If I want to put this `FirstDayOfWeek()` in a new class, should I make it as default or static (Instance or Static)? So if there's an update for this method I don't need to tweak it in 5 forms.
2. Which has better performance; Instance, Static or just Procedural code (copy and paste)?

Comment: What does the method return? The first day of the *current* week (so a `DateTime`) or a weekday (`DayOfWeek.Sunday`, `DayOfWeek.Monday`)? Does it depend on user preferences and/or locale?

Comment: the method returning datetime. `Does it depend on user preferences and/or locale? ` what does it mean ? its more customize method. i just worry about heap-stack memory. and worry about the performance

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is simple, but without additional context it can lead to overapplication of the same pattern in more complex scenarios where it is no longer correct to do so.

**The short answer**

Statics are the way to go in this case. The main reason being that this is a helper method whose result is not bound by a given context.

**The long answer**

The correct method depends on the goal of the method and how it achieves this.

Static methods should be used in cases where the method's purpose is not contextual and globally applicable. The logic required to find the first day of the week is always the same.

However, suppose your users are able to choose which day is the first day of the week (Sat/Sun/Mon). Now your logic to find the first day of the week is **contextual and no longer globally correct** (it depends on the user). While this can still be done using statics by passing the user (or their chosen day); this becomes more cumbersome when you consider more complicated example.
The better option here is to use dependency injection to inject behavior. Create multiple classes, each being an implementation of the same base class. This is a very complex topic that I can't explain from scratch, but I hope the key difference (contextuality) is clear.

**Performance**

There is no meaningful difference between static and instanced methods. The cost of instantiating an object is massively negligible. The only thing that can impact performance is if you have expensive logic in your constructor, but that would imply that you *need* this expensive logic in the constructor and thus cannot work without it, so it's still not really an issue that you should work to avoid (any more than you otherwise would).

**As an aside:**

> Procedural code (copy and paste)

That's not procedural code. Procedural code suggests that it is *generated* by some tool (pun not intended), not copy/pasted by a developer.

Copy/pasted code is never the right approach, unless you can prove that these multiple instances are functionally independent of each other. In other words: they can become very different things, and the fact that they currently do the same thing is *coincidence*; there is no requirement that when you update one you must update all the others.
*Spoiler alert: 9 times out of 10 when developers think multiple instances of the same method is the right approach, it's not.*

Comment: Procedural code, rather procedural programming, is a style of programming centered around procedures, or subroutines, not tool generated code. Otherwise +1.

Answer (score 0):

You [shouldn't worry too much about performance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/33020/173647) here. This method isn't going to be called hundreds of times per second. You do worry about reusability, which is great (and not limited to OOP, by the way).

If you just need a simple method which returns the first day of the *current* week, create a static method in a [Utility class](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/232880/173647):

```
public static class Utility {
    public static DateTime FirstDayOfCurrentWeek() {
        // your code goes here
    }
}
```

This way, it's the simplest to call from your forms (or anywhere else in the application).

If you get many more of these methods, create separate utility classes like `DateUtility`, `StringUtility`, etc.

Comment: so you are suggesting that if i have another method, i need to create new static class ? 1 static class for 1 static method ?

Comment: In theory, if they aren't logically related, they should be in separate classes. But if you have five Utility-type methods, I wouldn't worry about separate classes; if you have a hundred, I would.

Comment: @chopperfield: That's a contextual decision. Usually, you see these separated based on general functionality (`DateHelper`, `StringHelper`, ...) as the _global_ nature of statics tends to imply that the static methods are globally applicable to a given type, thus separating on said type.

Comment: Downvote because of the use of "utility" class where it's clearly not needed. This is a common domain problem, where a "Calendar" object may be exactly the place to put a method like this. [Naming is hard](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html), and pointing the correct naming to things makes a whole difference on your development practices, specially if you use Domain Driven Design. EDIT: I'll gladly upvote this if y ou change from a generic "Utility" class to a "Calendar" one.

Answer (score 0):

If the code for `FirstDayOfWeek` is something like:

```
DayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeek() => DayOfWeek.Monday;
```

ie, the value returned is hard-coded, then make it a static method.

If the code instead determines which day is the first day of the week based on the user's configuration or locale, then it should be an instance method and should be exposed to those forms via an interface and dependency injection.

Comment: for my case is- first day of week were sunday, and i need to make it monday, because the value for day were different (for calculation) hence i need to make it static method

Answer (score 0):

**[Naming is hard](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)**. If you properly name your objects and what they're doing, things get a little bit clear.

So, let's **assume** you're trying to create some sort of Calendar object or extended DateTime API.

What you are describing may fall into 3 distinct categories:

1. A [Factory Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) which would be static, and may always return the same object given you have no parameters.
2. A simple [Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties), which may be read-only depending upon your domain model and your object, which would NOT be static.
3. A [constant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-constants) which could be visible outside your class or not, depending upon your architecture.

All 3 of them are correct, depending on the context.

So, without more information about what does "First Day of Week" mean, with the proper naming of your object and a little bit more information about the problem you're trying to solve, there's no possible way to give you a fair advice.

**Naming is hard**.

Side note: **Dates and Times are also hard**. You can understand that by a quick peak on the  [number of articles on TheDailyWTF](https://www.google.com/search?q=date+site%3Athedailywtf.com) about it. I'd strongly suggest you take a look into [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) if you need anything advanced prior developing your own date/time manipulating functions.

Side note 2: **First Day of Week** is a malleable concept, which involves [calendar days](http://chartsbin.com/view/41671) (check [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MapPorn/comments/35hb3a/first_day_of_the_week_in_different_countries/) as well) and business days.

Comment: thanks for your insight. for my case is where as the parameter is `Datetime.Now` which will return the date of first week. e.g. parameter (26Jan19) will return 21Jan19, i need to make it custom where data from database and computer for the first week is different. from data were `monday` as computer were `sunday`

Comment: That's good. It seems you need something to work the same way as the [CultureInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912105/how-can-i-determine-that-the-start-of-week-is-monday-or-sunday-in-different-cult/35912236) object does. I suggest you edit your first post and add the example you showed, so that'll help other people understand it better and give other answers as well. StackOverflow has a few examples, like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039/how-can-i-get-the-datetime-for-the-start-of-the-week/14609184)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553208/240309)**.

Comment: Also, if you notice, the examples on SO that I've linked uses a 4th option, which is to create Extension Methods to the DateTime struct. Given you're working with .Net I think it's a perfectly valid solution to reduce the noise and boilerplate code for simple stuff. A CustomDateTimeExtensions class with your specific methods is a valid approach.